# How do I mount an encrypted /home directory with Linux Mint 18.3 KDE?

Tags: ubuntu, ecryptfs

I decided to figure out how to recover data on a disk if the system does not start.
It's better to do it before it happens;)

Since there is no definitive correct answer for Linux Mint 18.3 KDE anywhere, I had to find a solution myself.

Good topic for other OS like "Ubuntu": https://askubuntu.com/questions/238047/how-do-i-mount-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-another-ubuntu-machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Boot PC from Live CD (Linux mint 18.3 KDE)
2. Run in console: `sudo ecryptfs-manager` and exit (select 4 => Enter) ([see bug 455709 `mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/455709/comments/14))

[image: sudo ecryptfs-manager result]

3. Find your encrypted `/home/UserName` directory by checking every device in Dolphin. In my case, it is located on a separate volume (But in your case, most likely this path will be inside the `home` folder like: `/media/mint/1234567-1233-1233-32423-1a95b2c5dc68/home/UserName`)

[image: encrypted home directory in separated volume]

4. Open dolphin in home directory "as root"

[image: Open dolphin in home directory "as root"]

5. Press `Alt + .` for show hidden files

[image]

6. Go to `.ecryptfs` folder inside and try to find `.Private` folder (in every new Folder you have to "Show hidden files" by pressing `Alt + .` !!!)
7. As final your `.Private` folder:

[image]

8. Press `F4` for opening console here
9. Run in console: `ecryptfs-recover-private ./.Private` **(Passphrase is your login PC Password !!! )**

[image]

10. Well done! Go to `/tmp/ecryptfs.JSiaYsbz` directory using `cd`

[image]

p.s. Use the flag `--rw` (in step 9) to mount the encrypted filesystem as read **and write** (read only as default!)